# Ignorar validação de erros em diretório de arquivos no Netbeans

Tags: php, laravel-5, netbeans

Estou criando uma aplicação Laravel e gosto de utilizar o Netbeans para isso. O problema é que o Laravel tem uma série de bibliotecas que ele mesmo implementa e que utilizam recursos de testes que fazem meu projeto "demonstrar" como se houvesse erros.

Existe alguma forma de configurar o Netbeans para que ele ignore um diretório no projeto e não valide se os códigos estão certo ou errados?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faço isso através do menu `Project Properties`, principalmente quando utilizo Bootstrap e códigos de terceiros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]